# NuxtUI form not firing on click event during unit testing with vitests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vuejs3, nuxt3, vitest

I have the following vue component

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import type {FormSubmitEvent} from "#ui/types";
import {boolean, object, ref, string, type InferType} from "yup";

const emit = defineEmits(["submit"]);

const schema = object({
  name: string().required("Name is required"),
  company: string().required("Company name is required"),
  email: string().email("Invalid email").required("Email is required"),
  password: string()
    .min(8, "Must be at least 8 characters")
    .required("Password is required"),
  passwordConf: string().oneOf([ref("password"), null], "Passwords must match"),
  terms: boolean().oneOf([true], "You must accept the terms and conditions"),
});

type Schema = InferType<typeof schema>;

const state = reactive({
  name: undefined,
  company: undefined,
  email: undefined,
  password: undefined,
  passwordConf: undefined,
  terms: undefined,
});

const onSubmit = (event: FormSubmitEvent<Schema>) => {
  console.log("Button Data: ", event.data);
  emit("submit", event.data);
};
</script>
<template>
  <UForm :schema="schema" :state="state" class="space-y-4" @submit="onSubmit">
    <UFormGroup label="Name" name="name">
      <UInput v-model="state.name" />
    </UFormGroup>

    <UFormGroup label="Company Name" name="company">
      <UInput v-model="state.company" />
    </UFormGroup>

    <UFormGroup label="Email" name="email">
      <UInput v-model="state.email" />
    </UFormGroup>

    <UFormGroup label="Password" name="password">
      <UInput v-model="state.password" type="password" />
    </UFormGroup>

    <UFormGroup label="Confirm Password" name="passwordConf">
      <UInput v-model="state.passwordConf" type="password" />
    </UFormGroup>

    <UCheckbox v-model="state.terms" name="terms">
      <template #label>
        I agree to the <ULink to="/terms">terms and conditions</ULink>
      </template>
    </UCheckbox>

    <UButton type="submit" id="submit"> Submit </UButton>
  </UForm>
</template>
```

and the following unit test

```
import { mountSuspended } from '@nuxt/test-utils/runtime';
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';
import AuthSignUp from '~/components/auth/SignUp.vue';

describe('Signup.vue', () => {
    it('renders form fields correctly', async () => {
        const wrapper = await mountSuspended(AuthSignUp);

        expect(wrapper.find('[name="name"]').exists()).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.find('[name="company"]').exists()).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.find('[name="email"]').exists()).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.find('[name="password"]').exists()).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.find('[name="passwordConf"]').exists()).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.find('[name="terms"]').exists()).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.find('button[type="submit"]').exists()).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('emits "submit" event with valid data', async () => {
        const wrapper = await mountSuspended(AuthSignUp);

        await wrapper.find('[name="name"]').setValue('John Doe');
        await wrapper.find('[name="company"]').setValue('Acme Inc.');
        await wrapper.find('[name="email"]').setValue('johndoe@example.com');
        await wrapper.find('[name="password"]').setValue('securepassword123');
        await wrapper.find('[name="passwordConf"]').setValue('securepassword123');
        await wrapper.find('[name="terms"]').setValue();

        await wrapper.find('button[type="submit"]').trigger('click');

        // Check that the "submit" event was emitted with the correct data
        expect(wrapper.emitted('submit')[0][0]).toStrictEqual({
            name: 'John Doe',
            company: 'Acme Inc.',
            email: 'johndoe@example.com',
            password: 'securepassword123',
            passwordConf: 'securepassword123',
            terms: true
        })
    });
});
```

The first unit test works fine all the items are rendering correctly, however, here is my question.

1. On the second unit test, from what I can gather the click trigger on the submit button is not triggering the onSubmit function on the form, is there another way of doing this?
2. How do I test if the form is validating correctly since the NuxtUI error fields have no unique tags or IDs to use to get a handle on them.